# CPU overheat and Freeze running Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fan, overheating, temperature

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with Chrome 85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) (64-bit) on a Thinkpad Yoga 460 laptop with 8GB RAM and 1TB SSD.

If I have more than 10 tabs open in Chrome my system often comes to a crawl or a complete freeze.  The fan starts going crazy.  When I can actually get to htop the CPU useage seems OK (not 100%) but dmesg shows CPU over heating

```
[371723.356218] mce: CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 35463)
[371723.356219] mce: CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 35463)
[371723.356221] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 54525)
[371723.356222] mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 54525)
[371723.356223] mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 54525)
[371723.356225] mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 54525)
[371723.357220] mce: CPU3: Core temperature/speed normal
[371723.357221] mce: CPU1: Core temperature/speed normal
[371723.357222] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
[371723.357223] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
[371723.357224] mce: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
[371723.357225] mce: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
```

BUT  not all the time.  Sometimes I also get this:
Usually if I hold the power button like to power it off (due to being frozen for too long) but let go before it actually powers off as it starts to respond again.

```
[378478.212711] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service,task=chrome,pid=129195,uid=1000
[378478.212786] Out of memory: Killed process 129195 (chrome) total-vm:5194428kB, anon-rss:233868kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:326524kB, UID:1000 pgtables:2684kB oom_score_adj:300
[378478.230448] oom_reaper: reaped process 129195 (chrome), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:325512kB
```

I tried changing to Firefox but it kept crashing with the Out of Memory error showing in dmesg.

I have a Mac Powerbook with pretty much the same specs and run 10-20 tabs open in Chrome on it with no issues.  Note, I had another Thinkpad prior to this one which also kept freezing with Chrome.

I upgraded the BIOS to lates version.  I changed from the propriatary NVIDIA driver to the open source one as I thought that might have been the issue.  And I turned off hardware acceleration in Chrome.

I don't know what else to do to troubleshoot this issue.

UPDATE - Issue is resolved:
I changed some settings in my system BIOS that seems to have fixed this issue.
I disabled Intel Hyper-threading
I disabled Speedstep
And I changed Adaptive Thermal from Max Performane to Balanced.
I'm not sure which of these might have fixed the issue.  When I get a chance I'll go back and set them one by one to see.  But for now everything seems to be OK.  My fan still fires up now and again but without the usual freeze.  It's been a few days now with no issues so looks like whatever was going on was resolved with the BIOS tweaks.

Comment: Within Chrome go more tools task manager and see which tabs are causing the out of memory. Are there specific sites causing this? As well do a memtest from the grub boot up screen to make sure the memory is actually fine.

Comment: Often times my laptop freezes before I can bring up the Chrome task manager.  I keep htop running in a terminal window and it is also improssible to switch to it whilst the freese is happeneing.  Then I either have to toally power off by holding the power button in, or it comes good after some time and by then I can't see any issues in htop but see the issues in dmesg as described in my original post.  On the times I do get the Chrome task manager open I have not established a patter around particular sites.

Comment: I would test the memory out, does this only happen with chrome, what about firefox?

Comment: Related, just install earlyoom. It will kill off the process causing a freeze, before it becomes a problem.

Comment: Please [don’t add “SOLVED” to the title](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7413/250300). In order to mark your question _solved_ in the right way, you should [_accept_ the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick mark (✓) next to it) that helped you. If you solved your problem yourself, please [post an answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) below. In this case, you'll have to wait 2 days before being able to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reliable solution I've been able to find is:

```
sudo apt install earlyoom
```

The "early **o**ut **o**f **m**emory"-killer will terminate any process that pushes your computer into disk thrashing and the resulting freezing. I think most Chrome developers have much more RAM than most users, so they hardly ever run into these sort of issues.

There is another more manual way of dealing with it: you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>SysRQ</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to manually invoke the OOM killer. But for that to work you need to enable it:

```
$ sudo sed -i s@#kernel.sysrq@kernel.sysrq@g /etc/sysctl.conf
$ sudo sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=1
```

<kbd>SysRQ</kbd> is labelled <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>  or <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>on many keyboards, and on some others you have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> to access it, making the full combination of keys<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>PrtScr</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>. On some keyboards only the right hand <kbd>Alt</kbd> works.

These methods essentially force the browser or offending application to crash, and free up its memory. There used to be browser addons that suspend background processes, but at the time of writing they cause more problems than they solve, so I won't link them - and nowadays most Chrome and Firefox just keep crashed tabs suspended in the background until you click on them, so the impact of a crash is minimal - but do check your add-ons as besides memory hungry web-apps, they are the most likely culprits.